# Как добавить изображение Pillow в PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pillow, qpixmap

Я хочу написать подобие редактора фотографий на языке *Python*. Для работы с фотографиями я использую библиотеку *Pillow*.

Проблема в том, что хочется создать не просто консольный вариант, 
а программу с пользовательским интерфейсом и предварительным просмотром изображений (для этого я использую *PyQt5*).

Каким образом можно в *PyQt5* вывести на экран изображение *Pillow*?

Пример:

```
image = Image.open('cat.jpg')
```

---

Единственное что я нашел, это обычный вывод изображений, путем открытия файла. Есть идея после каждого изменения сохранять файл **cat.jpg** и открывать его через *PyQt5*, но это будет очень не оптимизировано. По крайней мере я так думаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

метод, для встраивания картинки Pillow в PyQt5 может выглядеть так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageFilter
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt


class Example(QWidget):               
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        image  = Image.open("img/cat.jpg")   
        image  = image.convert("RGBA")

        qim = ImageQt(image)

        self.pixmap = QPixmap(QImage(qim))
        label = QLabel()
        label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")  
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]